# Scrapy crawler not processing XHR Request

Tags: python, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest, scrapy, scrape

My spider is only crawling the first 10 pages, so I am assuming it is not entering the load more button though the Request.

I am scraping this website: http://www.t3.com/reviews.

My spider code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.conf import settings
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from reviews.items import ReviewItem


class T3Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "t3" #spider name to call in terminal
    allowed_domains = ['t3.com'] #the domain where the spider is allowed to crawl
    start_urls = ['http://www.t3.com/reviews'] #url from which the spider will start crawling

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        review_links = sel.xpath('//div[@id="content"]//div/div/a/@href').extract()
        for link in review_links:
            yield Request(url="http://www.t3.com"+link, callback=self.parse_review)
#if there is a load-more button:
        if sel.xpath('//*[@class="load-more"]'):
            req = Request(url=r'http://www\.t3\.com/more/reviews/latest/\d+', headers = {"Referer": "http://www.t3.com/reviews", "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}, callback=self.parse)
            yield req
        else:
            return

    def parse_review(self, response):
        pass #all my scraped item fields
```

What I am doing wrong? Sorry but I am quite new to scrapy. Thanks for your time, patience and help.

Comment: I don't see `load-more` button anywhere on the page.

Comment: http://imgur.com/dPPmSNi is in the end of the page @alecxe

Comment: Interesting, in google chrome I see More Reviews link which redirects me to the archive. In Firefox, yes, I see "Load more", strange :)

Comment: thats quite strange... I open now on chrome and still can view the load more button and not see any "more review"... wow...and in that archive if you choose any month it will not redirects you only for the newst review?? @alecxe

Comment: http://imgur.com/15UK81O look :) in chrome and still see load more button... @alecxe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the "Load More" button, you would not find any indication of how the link to load more reviews is constructed. The idea behind is rather easy - the numbers after `http://www.t3.com/more/reviews/latest/` suspiciously look like a timestamp of the last loaded article. Here is how you can get it:

```
import calendar

from dateutil.parser import parse
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request


class T3Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "t3"
    allowed_domains = ['t3.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.t3.com/reviews']

    def parse(self, response):
        reviews = response.css('div.listingResult')
        for review in reviews:
            link = review.xpath("a/@href").extract()[0]
            yield Request(url="http://www.t3.com" + link, callback=self.parse_review)

        # TODO: handle exceptions here

        # extract the review date
        time = reviews[-1].xpath(".//time/@datetime").extract()[0]

        # convert a date into a timestamp
        timestamp = calendar.timegm(parse(time).timetuple())

        url = 'http://www.t3.com/more/reviews/latest/%d' % timestamp
        req = Request(url=url,
                      headers={"Referer": "http://www.t3.com/reviews", "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"},
                      callback=self.parse)
        yield req

    def parse_review(self, response):
        print response.url
```

Notes:

- this requires [`dateutil`](https://labix.org/python-dateutil) module to be installed
- you should recheck the code and make sure you are getting all of the reviews without skipping any of them
- you should somehow end this "Load more" thing

Comment: how you know the numbers after http://www.t3.com/more/reviews/latest/"1427368799" how do you find it is a timestamp of the last loaded article ?? @alecxe

Comment: @InêsMartins I've inspected the XHR requests sent by the browser, loaded the numbers at the end of URL to datetime and figured out these are the time stamps of the last loaded articles. I hope I've implemented it correctly in the proposed sample code.

Comment: it worked :) thanks so much! just a curious thing is that in scrapinghub  is throwing the error "ImportError: No module named dateutil.parser" but locally is working... and I have instaled dateutil @alecxe

Comment: "you should somehow end this "Load more" thing" what you mean from that? @alecxe